# Instructions on installing Tachyon in DCOS (Mesosphere)?

Tags: dcos, spark-notebook, alluxio

I have spark-notebook setup in DCOS.  Tachyon is part of the ecosystem.  But I couldn't find any DCOS-way instructions on getting Tachyon installed.  I could install it from scratch but there seems to be some DCOS-compliance way to get a service installed/registered?

Thx. J